# Why doesn't `git clone` clone all the branches?

Tags: git, github

If I do

```
$ git clone https://github.com/dtu-compute/docker-mongodb
$ cd docker-mongodb
$ git branch
* master
```

but if you look at [the Github branch page](https://github.com/dtu-compute/docker-mongodb/branches), there are two branches.

**Question**

Why don't I get all the branches with `git clone`?

Comment: if you checkout the branch you will see it works fine

Comment: But why isn't it listed? have it something to do how the branch were pushed?

Comment: `git branch -a` will list all of them

Comment: If a remote repo has no master branch, you may ask why `git clone` clones nothing. In fact, it clones everything if no option like --single-branch or --depth is used. They are hidden at first. `git branch` only lists the local branches.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`git branch` only shows local branches by default; use `git branch -r` to see remote branches or `git branch -a` to see all. `git clone` only creates one local branch, `master` by default, which tracks (again, by default) the `master` branch on the remote repository.

Comment: But then what about when you want to work on one of those branches that exist remotely but not locally? If I run `git checkout exists-remotely` it says it's created a new branch, which presumably branches off master. How would you ensure you're getting the existing, *remote* `exists-remotely` rather than making a new one?

Comment: You presume wrong. "If <branch> is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in
           exactly one remote (call it <remote>) with a matching name and
           --no-guess is not specified, treat as equivalent to

               $ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>"

Comment: OK so when I clone a repo, and I end up with just master, and I then checkout a branch that isn't listed locally but I know exists remotely, why then does it tell me it's switched "to a new branch" and the files/code differ from the remote branch of the same name? Struggling to get my head around this.

Comment: Because it creates a new *tracking* branch that mirrors the remote, not a new branch based on your currently checked out branch, before switching.

Comment: Thanks, that clears that up. Appreciated.